# ABPeoplePickerNavigationController crashes on init

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm using ABPeoplePickerNavigationController in my project.  I have a line that looks like this:

```
ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *peoplePicker = [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];
```

It works fine when I have my deployment target set to 4.3.  When I change the deployment target to 4.2, it crashes on this line w/ EXC_BAD_ACCESS.  I ran w/ NSZombieEnabled and no zombies turned up.

Comment: How did you come to know app is crashing on this statement ? Did you try to debug ? It should absolutely work on deployment target 4.2, you must be having error at some other place not on this statement I believe.

Comment: @Jennis - that's what I'm afraid of.  I found it was this line because that's the line the debugger stopped on and highlighted with the EXC_BAD_ACCESS message.  I even split up the alloc and the init into 2 different lines and it appears to be in the init.  When I step into the init itself it's just down in bytecode and I can't make heads of it.  But it may be like you said - a bug somewhere else in the code.  The weird thing is it only did it after changing the target to 4.2

Answer (score 0):

It works fine in 4.2.

1. Clean All Target.
2. Delete App, Turn off iPhone and Xcode.
3. Project Info => Check Base SDK (General Tab & Build Tab)

Comment: I cleaned, deleted, restarted as indicated.  Still no good.  I've seen people recommend developing to the latest Base SDK, but setting the deployment target to the earliest OS version support is planned for.  Given that, I have my Base SDK set to 4.3 and my deployment target at 4.2.